# Calling an index value within an array

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and I am stuck with trying to call the index value of an array. I would like to be able to say "Player 2 is the heaviest and he weighs 72kg" but I cant seem to get the index value of the max weight array. any help is much appreciated and I am sorry my code is a mess but I have only started to learn c sharp.

```
{
    double[] weight;
    double[] height;
    double totalHeight = 0;
    double totalWeight = 0;
    double averageHeight = 0;
    double averageWeight = 0;
    double maxWeightIndex =0;
    double maxHeightIndex =0;

    weight = new double [5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double maxWeight = weight[0];

    height = new double [5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double maxHeight = weight[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < weight.Length ; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the weight of player " + (i+1) );  //asking user to what the weight of a player is 
        weight[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("What is the height of player " + (i+1));     //asking user to what the height of a player is
        height[i]= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        totalHeight += height[i];               // total height 
        totalWeight += weight[i];               // total weight

        averageHeight = (totalHeight/ weight.Length );      //average height
        averageWeight = (totalWeight/ weight.Length );      //average weight 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < weight.Length ; i++)    
    {
        if (maxWeight < weight[i]) maxWeight = weight[i];               //max value of weight
        if (maxHeight < height[i]) maxHeight = height[i];               // max value of height 



        if (maxWeight < weight[i]) maxWeightIndex = i;                  //attempt at getting max weight index value 

        if (maxHeight < height[i]) maxHeightIndex = i;                  //attempt at getting max height index value

     }  

    Console.WriteLine("The total weight of the team is " + totalWeight + "kg's");
    Console.WriteLine("The total height of the team is " + totalHeight + "cm's");
    Console.WriteLine("The average height of the team is " + averageHeight + "cm's");
    Console.WriteLine("The average weight of the team is " +  averageWeight + "kg's");
    Console.WriteLine("Player " + maxWeightIndex + " is the heaviest player and he weighs " + maxWeight + "kg's");
    Console.WriteLine("Player " + maxHeightIndex + " is the tallest player and he is " + maxHeight + "cm's");


}
```

Comment: You are changing `maxWeight` first and then testing *again* if it less than the value you just changed it to. Obviously this will be `false`. Why aren't you assigning both variables within the same `if` clause (use braces `{ ... }`)?

Comment: `averageHeight = (totalHeight/ weight.Length );`  See `weight`, should be `height`

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, `height` or `weight` differ only by a single character, so I recommend choosing a synonym for one or both to distinguish them more clearly.  "mass" in place of weight would work, perhaps?  Anyway, just a thought.

Comment: yes i understand you... just to make it easier to clearify which is which thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are overwriting maxWeight and maxHeight, so the second if clause will always be false.

```
for (int i = 0; i < weight.Length ; i++)    
{
    if (maxWeight < weight[i]) maxWeight = weight[i];
    if (maxHeight < height[i]) maxHeight = height[i];
    // maxWeight == weight[i] here so the result is false.
    if (maxWeight < weight[i]) maxWeightIndex = i;
    if (maxHeight < height[i]) maxHeightIndex = i;
}
```

better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weight.Length ; i++)    
{
    if (maxWeight < weight[i]){
        maxWeight = weight[i];
        maxWeightIndex = i;
    }
    if (maxHeight < height[i]){ 
        maxHeight = height[i];
        maxHeightIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for me thank you so much i have spent the last 2 hours trying to solve this

Comment: Your welcome. Don't forget to also correct the error Amy found. (see her comment underneath your question)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < weight.Length ; i++)    
{
    if (maxWeight < weight[i]) maxWeight = weight[i];               //max value of weight
    if (maxHeight < height[i]) maxHeight = height[i];               // max value of height 



    if (maxWeight < weight[i]) maxWeightIndex = i;                  //attempt at getting max weight index value 

    if (maxHeight < height[i]) maxHeightIndex = i;                  //attempt at getting max height index value

}
```

to

```
  for (int i = 0; i < weight.Length ; i++)    
    {
        if (maxWeight < weight[i])
        {
            maxWeight = weight[i];               //max value of weight
            maxWeightIndex = i;                 //attempt at getting max weight index value 
        }
        if (maxHeight < height[i]) 
        {
            maxHeight = height[i];               // max value of height 
            maxHeightIndex = i;                 //attempt at getting max height index value
        }                  
    }
```

The problem is you are setting maxWeight to the new max weight and then checking max weight against the current weight again. This way, the check happens once and both variables are changed.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you set maxWeight to equal weight[i] at that index in this line.

```
if (maxWeight < weight[i]) maxWeight = weight[i];
```

You can either immediately assign i to another variable in the same if statement, or to proceed with your second if, you would want to equate it as they would now be equal

```
if (maxWeight == weight[i]) maxWeightIndex = i;
```

Comment: This will most likely produce wrong results due to float/double inaccuracy

Answer (score -1):

If i am right you are trying to get both the max value of `height[]` and maximum value of `weight[]` index value?

You dont have to do a `for loop` to check and filter an array element.

To get the maximum value of your arrays you can use the method `.max()`:

```
double maxWeight = weight.max();
double maxHeight = height.max();

// then you can use an `.ToList().IndexOf(value)` to get the index.
int maxWeightIndex = weight.ToList().IndexOf(maxWeight);
int maxHeightIndex = height.ToList().IndexOf(maxHeight);
```